# Does Visual Studio 2010 work with SharePoint 2007?

Tags: visual-studio, 2007

Does Visual Studio 2010 work with MOSS 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Vs2010 only works with SharePoint 2010. For Moss 2007 you'll need VS2008

Answer (score 2):

You can however use [SPVisualDev](http://spvisualdev.codeplex.com/) that works with VS2010 for SP2007 solutions.

Answer (score 1):

All of the Templates in VS2010 are designed for SP2010, and likely won't work for SP2007 without modification.

I know of no reason you couldn't create a project for SP2007 and do all the work that VS2010 does for SP2010 manually (Build the WSP, generate various Xml files), OR use [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/), or another 3rd party tool.

**Edit:** Johan is correct, [SPVisualDev](http://spvisualdev.codeplex.com/) is what I was thinking of.